# How to disable updates available message in Discover?

Tags: updates, kubuntu, 22.04

I am running Kubuntu 22.04.

Sometimes, right after startup, Discover shows "Update available" in its tray icon.

I update my system regularly from the command line, and don't want to see this "Update available" message. How to disable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the system tray is usually an icon you can use to show hidden icons. Select this icon with a rightclick and select `Configure System Tray...` from the context menu. In the `System Tray Settings`-window chose the `Entries`-Tab and there chose the desired action for `Updates`:
[image]

---

If you don't want Discover to check for available updates at all:

It's a program called [DiscoverNotifier](https://github.com/KDE/discover/blob/master/notifier/DiscoverNotifier.cpp) which is checking for available updates. Seems it only checks if updates are available, the package list seems to be only updated when you click the icon which will open `Discover` then and fetch the updates.This program is launched in the background through a `.desktop`-file in `/etc/xdg/autostart`.

Remove the file `/etc/xdg/autostart/org.kde.discover.notifier.desktop` so `DicoverNotifier` will not  be started automatically. To reenable,  simply copy the file from `/usr/share/applications/org.kde.discover.notifier.desktop` back to `/etc/xdg/autostart/`.

This program also provides the system tray icon which will not be available at all if the program is not running.

Comment: Thanks. remove it from /etc/xdg/autostart does the magic!